# TypeError: getDb is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need your help on this error "TypeError: getDb is not a function"

I am using Mongodb v3.0 or later
Node.js

I have this Error when creating an item.

See the portion of code with the error below

```js
save() {

    const db = getDb();

    return db.collection('products')

      .insertOne(this)

      .then(result => {

        console.log(result);

      })

      .catch(err => {

        console.log(err);

      });

  }

}
```

Comment: can you also add your `getDB` function and is it declared in the same file?

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this and see if you can reproduce the issue there? Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @Evert vd H. There was an error in my database connection code.

I exported this.getDb => export.getDb = this.getDb;

Instead

 export.getDb = getDb;

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelOga, perhaps you can submit an answer to the question so it can be obvious the issue described in the question is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you connect with mongodb.MongoClient, you need to specify database to be use. So, getDb() should be like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  mongodb.MongoClient.connect("URL", function (err, db) { //Use your conn URL
    if(err) 
        reject(err);
    resolve(db.db("database")); //Use your DB name
});
```

I think this would resolve your query. As without seeing getDB(), I can only help you with this. For next time, try to add require info so that other can understand or reproduce same.

Answer (score 0):

```
_db = client.db('nodeShop'); // nodeShop is the name of the database.
```

Comment: Please add some description and elaborate your answer for the clarity.